# Running WatiN with Firefox on localhost

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, watin

I'm trying to run watin with firefox on a localhost, but there seems to be an error:

> WatiN.Core.Native.Mozilla.FireFoxException: Unable to connect to jssh server, please make sure you have correctly installed the jssh.xpi plugin

I'm using firefox 3.6 and already install the plugin. It works when I'm not using localhost. Is there a workaround/solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[Like the documentation says](http://watin.sourceforge.net/setting-up-firefox-for-testing.html) you need to install the jssh.xpi plugin, that link has step by step instructions.

It does not give latest jssh link and there is no authority for it but have a look to the matrix in step 2 of [instructions for Watir](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/FireWatir+Installation) or if it is Windows Firefox 3.6, [download directly](http://wiki.openqa.org/download/attachments/13893658/jssh-3.6-WINNT.xpi?version=1&modificationDate=1264489925906)

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you installed WatiN via NuGet, then you'll have to find the `.xpi` file in your `packages` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I get this occasionally.  There's been a bug submitted for this: -

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3356073&group_id=167632&atid=843727

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on server.  I could run the application fine under my own login, but when set up as a scheduled task, it wouldn't work.  Eventually worked out that because the app was running under a different login (a domain service account), it didn't have permission to access the JSSH Firefox plugin.

[This Blog Post](http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/tag/jssh/) describes the situation (and resolution) in much more detail, but basically, when you install an add-on to FireFox, it is installed for the current user, but not globally.  The add-on must be installed globally (i.e. for all users) to work.

I couldn't get the command line option mentioned in the link to work, so I logged onto the server using the service account, and added the JSSH add-on manually.

In your case, it could be that using "localhost", is forcing your application to run under a different account, which does not have access to the JSSH plugin in FireFox.